# Else's or Elses' or Elses

Tags: apostrophe

In the statement:

**In life, try to often make yourself a minor character in someone elses novel.**

*where* - if anywhere - does the apostrophe go?

Comment: It's a possessive form: *else's*.

Comment: I must misunderstand the purpose of englsh.stackexchange.com if this is off topic.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's "else's". Here, *someone else* is a singular compound noun, and the novel belongs to them. The possessive apostrophe is used.

Comment: Thank you. I will tick this. Is there ANY time that it's *elses'* ?

Comment: I can't think of any situation where you'd ever have the plural *elses*, since it's either an adverb, adjective, or part of a singular or uncountable compound noun. So, with no plural form, you'd never see the plural possessive form *elses'*.

Comment: An established user like yourself should know to vote to close questions like this rather than answer them.

Comment: Thank you for answering this question and not closing it, it's the first google result when looking and it explains why it is how it is and isn't how it's not.

Comment: It would be a real shame to have closed this question. I too found this question and answer helpful.

Comment: It's a real shame that this question has been closed, but at least it hasn't been deleted.  And the reason given for closure is false, and directly contricts the FAQ for this stack.  Specifically, this quesiton is on topic according the these reasons:
Questions on the following topics are welcomed here: 
Word choice and usage,
Grammar,
Spelling and punctuation.